# Canonicalise args and kwargs to argument-canonical form

Tags: python, variadic-functions

I'm looking for a way, given a function's signature, to canonicalize it's args and kwargs. That is, any kwargs passed in already in the signature of the function should be converted to args.

For example:

```
def myfunc(a, b=0, c=0, **kwargs):
    pass

def canonicalize(func, *args, **kwargs):
    something = inspect.signature(func)
    # Do something with args/kwargs here
    return new_args, new_kwargs
```

Example output:

```
>>> canonicalize(myfunc, 1, 2, g=3)
(1, 2), {'g': 3}
>>> canonicalize(myfunc, 1)
(1,), {}
>>> canonicalize(myfunc, 1, b=2)
(1, 2), {}
>>> canonicalize(myfunc, 1, g=3, b=2)
(1, 2), {'g': 3}
>>> canonicalize(myfunc, 1, g=3, c=2)
(1, 0, 2), {'g': 3}
```

Comment: There's no reason to consider the positional form any more canonical than the keyword form.

Comment: This is especially the case with the awkward handling you show for default argument values, where defaults are only explicitly included in the resulting tuple if later arguments were passed by keyword.

Comment: @user2357112 Would you have an answer for the keyword form (where the defaults won't be in the kwargs)? That would also be very useful to me. :-)

Comment: I've edited the question to show keyword-canonical form.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi if you have a new question with different criteria - then please ask it as a new question... it confuses things changing the question after it's already been answered as now the answer doesn't make sense - thanks.

Comment: Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900925/canonicalise-args-and-kwargs-to-kwarg-canonical-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) and its `bind(...)` method, eg:

```
bound_args = inspect.signature(myfunc).bind(1, g=3, c=2)
# <BoundArguments (a=1, c=2, kwargs={'g': 3})>
```

Then access what you need from the [`BoundArguments`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.BoundArguments) object, eg:

```
bound_args.apply_defaults()
args = bound_args.args
kwargs = bound_args.kwargs
```